# How can I center my logo in the navigation using the Responsive Grid System?

Tags: css, html, navigation

I'm wondering how to properly center my Logo having it within the top navigation. When it condenses everything gets messed up. I want it to turn into one of those 'square' drop down menus. 
I want the links to be 'even' on either side.

HTML:

```
<div id="navigationcontainer">
        <nav>
            <ul>
            <div class="col span_1_of_9">
                <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                </div>

            <div class="col span_1_of_9">   
                <li><a href="">about</a></li>
                </div>

             <div class="col span_1_of_9">              
                <li><a href="">services</a></li>
                </div>

            <div class="col span_3_of_10">
                                <li><a id="logo" href="/"><img src="images/CarpetRepair_Logo.png" alt="Logo"></a></li>
                                </div>
                         <div class="col span_1_of_9">
                <li><a href="">photos</a></li>
                </div>

                <div class="col span_1_of_9">
                <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
                </div>

                <div class="col span_1_of_9">
                <li><a id="FB" href="/"><img src="images/FB_Logo.jpg" alt="Facebook"></a></li>
                </div>
                         </div>             
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
width: 254px;
height: 170px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: -34px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 }


a#logo { 
    float:left;
    min-width: 50%;
    width:100%; }

#FB {


 }

#navigationcontainer {
        width: 100%;    
        height: 74px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        background: #06060C left top;
    }


        nav {                   
            clear: both;
            width: 80%; /* 1000px / 1250px */
            font-size: 0.8125em; /* 13 / 16 */
            max-width: 92.3em; /* 1200px / 13 */
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 34px;
            color: #c39a6e;

        }

        nav ul {        
        font-family: 'ostrich_sansmedium';
        font-size: 1.45em;
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        list-style: none;
        }

        nav ul li {     

        display: block; 
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        }

        nav li ul {
        display: none;
        }

        nav ul li a {
        margin-top: 8px;
        display: block;     
        padding: 7px 15px 3px 15px;
        text-align: center;
        }
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#logo {
    margin-top: -34px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
 }


a#logo { 
    float: left;
    min-width: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><a id="logo" href="/"><img src="/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="Logo" width="170px"></a></li>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yka0kgvz/

Comment: Hello, that sorta works. Except now the logo does no automatically resize. And the navigation list still gets jumbled when minimizing. (:

Comment: You would need to remove the width=170px;" from the HTML and add a min-width:#px; for to the #navigationcontainer to stop the menu from getting jumbled. Updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yka0kgvz/1/